# How i will insert matrices in an array in python

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have 50 matrix(x1,x2...x50) of images of size 1028x1028. if I print the shape of any one among 50 matrix like this =>

```
print(x1.shape)
```

It will return (1028,1028).

I want to insert those matrices in an linear array(A) by using numpy or another else . when I Will `print(A.shape)` it will print (50,1028,1028).
How I will do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I feel strange for having to point that out, but

```
numpy.array([x1,x2,x3,...,x50])
```

will do that.

Also, it's a bad idea to have 50 separate variables `x1`, `x2` and so on. Just put them into a list `x` and address them as `x[0]`, `x[1]`, and so on.

Comment: yes, i will not store it like x1 ...x50. I will read an image-matrix and store it in linear array .. so which function i will use. after that when i use A.shape it will return (50,1028,1028).

Comment: u told me to store it in list .bt if i use list_name.shape. it will show list function don't have any shape .

Comment: seriously, if you run exactly the line of code I posted, it will give you what you demanded. I'm not sure what you're doing.